# How to extract values from tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape odds data from a site. Trying to keep things simple, this is where I've got at this moment

I successfully connect and retrieve the page(s) content, so I'll omit previous steps to get straight to te point

```
[...]
page_response = requests.get(page_link, timeout=5)
# parse html
page_content = BeautifulSoup(page_response.content, "html.parser")

rows = []
rows_list = page_content.find_all('tr')
```

(Showing only first row, just to keep it simple)

```
rows_list[1]
```

returns this

```
<tr><td class="h-text-left"><a class="in-match" href="/soccer/algeria/ligue-1/constantine-mo-bejaia/84nzpMc0/"><span><strong>Constantine</strong></span> - <span>MO Bejaia</span></a></td><td class="h-text-center"><a href="/soccer/algeria/ligue-1/constantine-mo-bejaia/84nzpMc0/">1:0</a></td><td class="table-main__odds colored"><span><span><span data-odd="1.73"></span></span></span></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="3.18"></td><td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="4.75"></td><td class="h-text-right h-text-no-wrap">27.01.</td></tr>
```

selecting  tags

```
row = rows_list[1].find_all('td')
row
```

returns

```
[<td class="h-text-left"><a class="in-match" href="/soccer/algeria/ligue-1/constantine-mo-bejaia/84nzpMc0/"><span><strong>Constantine</strong></span> - <span>MO Bejaia</span></a></td>,
<td class="h-text-center"><a href="/soccer/algeria/ligue-1/constantine-mo-bejaia/84nzpMc0/">1:0</a></td>,
<td class="table-main__odds colored"><span><span><span data-odd="1.73"></span></span></span></td>,
<td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="3.18"></td>,
<td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="4.75"></td>,
<td class="h-text-right h-text-no-wrap">27.01.</td>]
```

The data I need is here, and for all the rows with "text" attribute is easy to retrieve

```
row[0].text
'Constantine - MO Bejaia'

row[1].text
'1:0'
```

but for these other rows I can't figure how to get the values of "data-odd"

```
row[2]
<td class="table-main__odds colored"><span><span><span data-odd="1.73"></span></span></span></td>

row[3]
<td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="3.18"></td>

row[4]
<td class="table-main__odds" data-odd="4.75"></td>
```

which would be 1.73, 3.18 and 4.75

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You can get this like `row['your index']['yourtag']` In your question :

```
row[3]['data-odd']
row[4]['data-odd']
```

I realize your `row[2]`'s `data-odd` is in span tag. so you get the span and then parse `data-odd` like:

```
    for a in row[2].findAll('span')[1] : ## [1] means getting the second span tag
        print a['data-odd']
```

Comment: this works fine, but on row[2] (the longest one) returns a key error.

Answer (score 0):

Those things are called tag attributes. If my memory serves well, you can get the *data-odd* value for your specific row by doing something like this:

```
row[2]['data-odd']
1.73
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like a `dict`. You can use

```
row[x].get('key')
```

or

```
row[x]['key']
```